# SQL query (without subqueries)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables:

```
user(id, name);

tasks(id, user_id, text, date);

bonus(id, user_id, sum, date, type).
```

I'm trying to write a query that will give me a list of all users, quantity of their tasks and a sum of bonuses of every type, each in separate column.

There are three types of bonuses:

```
type = (1, 2, 3)
```

So, I mean a table, which looks like this

```
name | task_count | bonus_1 | bonus_2 | bonus_3
```

Comment: which "sql" engine are you using MS-SQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc

Comment: I didn't like the result I get using join on each bonus type. PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.name, 
        t.task_count, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.type=1 then b.sum END) AS bonus_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.type=2 then b.sum END) AS bonus_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.type=3 then b.sum END) AS bonus_3
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS task_count 
           FROM tasks 
           GROUP BY user_id) t ON t.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN bonus b ON b.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id,u.name,t.task_count
```

Comment: Great! One more question. What if I have one more table 'comments(user_id, comment, task_id)' and I need one more field in the result table with quantity of the comments of all tasks related with each user.

name | task_count | bonus_1 | bonus_2 | bonus_3 | comments_count

Comment: Sorry. Lost interest in this question now. If that's what you wanted you should have stated it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: the following won't work! Retained for information

```
SELECT
    user.name,
    COUNT(tasks.id) AS task_count,
    SUM(bonus1.sum) AS bonus_1,
    SUM(bonus2.sum) AS bonus_2,
    SUM(bonus3.sum) AS bonus_3
FROM user
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks ON tasks.user_id = user.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bonus1 ON bonus1.user_id = user.id
        AND bonus1.type = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bonus2 ON bonus2.user_id = user.id
        AND bonus1.type = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bonus3 ON bonus3.user_id = user.id
        AND bonus1.type = 3
GROUP BY
    user.name
ORDER BY
    user.name
```

You might need to handle `NULL` values specially if it is not the case that every user will always have at least one task and at least one of each type of bonus.

Comment: This will cause mini cartesian joins that mess up the `sum`. If a user has x tasks then each bonus row will get multiplied x times.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the different aggregates will interfere with eachother.  For a user with 2 tasks, each bonus will be counted twice.  And the same for a user with 2 type=1 bonuses.

Comment: @Martin good point, I guess that means it can't be done without a sub-query

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the aggregation before joining on `user`.  For example:

```
select  u.name
,       t.task_count
,       b.bonus_1
,       b.bonus_2
,       b.bonus_3
,       t.comment_count
from    user u
left join
        (
        select  user_id
        ,       count(distinct t.id) as task_count
        ,       count(distinct c.id) as comment_count
        from    tasks t
        left join
                comment c
        on      c.task_id = t.id
        group by
                t.user_id
        ) t
on      t.user_id = u.id
left join
        (
        select  user_id
        ,       sum(case when type = 1 then sum end) as bonus_1
        ,       sum(case when type = 2 then sum end) as bonus_3
        ,       sum(case when type = 3 then sum end) as bonus_2
        from    bonus
        group by
                user_id
        ) b
on      b.user_id = u.id
```